# SQL Injection | org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.update can be vulnerable to SQL injection (with Spring JDBC))

Tags: java, sql, sonarqube, sql-injection, jdbctemplate

I need your help/discuss the following code has the chance for SQL injection or not.

`UPDATE_SQL_QUERY` has a update query with `?` and has no concatenation:

```sql
update STUDENT set studentName = ? where  studentId= ?
```

`values` variable (Object[]) holds the values for the respective ? value and `typeList` variable holds

```
final int[] types = {
            Types.VARCHAR,
            Types.VARCHAR
}
jdbcTemplate.update(UPDATE_SQL_QUERY, values, typeList);
```

Actual code:

behind the scene, it calls the jdbcTemplate

```
@Override
public int update(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes) throws DataAccessException {
    return update(sql, newArgTypePreparedStatementSetter(args, argTypes));
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see the SQL injection chance here in the code unless the driver has some bug in it. I need your help to confirm or discuss on this, whether this actually have some vulnerable code or false positive in Sonar. Our code base DAO layer has this code in more places as well.

The Sonar report highlights this code with the following

> This use of
> org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.update(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;[I)I
> can be vulnerable to SQL injection (with Spring JDBC)

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Is it possible that `UPDATE_SQL_QUERY` is not declared final? And how is it constructed? Why are you quoting the `update(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes)` method, as that is `JdbcTemplate` code, not your own code, but the way you posted it somewhat suggests that it's your own code.

Comment: Also specify which exact Sonar rule is triggered.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel UPDATE_SQL_QUERY is declared as final  , the query value is in the property file and it set via constructor param by passing 
@Value("${update.sql}") final String UPDATE_SQL_QUERY,

Comment: That could potentially be the reason why it is flagged: it comes from somewhere external to your Java code. But to be clear, that is just a guess, I'm not sure exactly how far Sonar goes in checking this.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel

Why are you quoting the update(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes) method, as that is JdbcTemplate code, not your own code, but the way you posted it somewhat suggests that it's your own code.-   ``I just give the spring jdbctemplate code which intent to call for better understanding.``